# How to dolphin dive in Battlefield1?

Tags: pc, battlefield-1

First of all, a *dolphin dive* is a term from [COD Black Ops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_of_Duty:_Black_Ops), 
[here's a video of what it looks like](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1enqkEGZm8).

I think the BF1 version is a bit different but I've seen people *flying* and then landing on the ground, how is it done?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7QpVX2JeEU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that, more or less, the same way you **charge**.

1. Start **sprinting**
2. After some steps, stop pressing **Shift** (*you'll keep sprinting
   for a short distance*) and press **Ctrl** (*you may have to press it
   for a short period of time, not just "one click"*)

---

This same thing can also be done when *Toggle Crouching* replacing **Ctrl** for **X**